# Nested joins and aliases with (Flask-)SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to switch from using raw SQL to SQLAlchemy/Flask-SQLAlchemy. As far as I learned simple queries, I can't understand how to use subqueries, nested joins and aliases.

Right now I have my SQL query:

```
SELECT device.*, wifi.name as room FROM
(SELECT * FROM devices WHERE mac="{0}") as device
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT w2.*, wifi_map.name as name FROM
        (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM wifi ORDER BY signal_pow DESC) as w1 GROUP BY device_id) as w2
        INNER JOIN wifi_map
        ON w2.bssid=wifi_map.bssid)
    as wifi
ON device.id=wifi.device_id
```

I managed to convert the `LEFT JOIN` part to SQLAlchemy (the one that's aliased as `wifi`). It looks like this:

```
sorted_wifi = db.session.query(WiFi).order_by(WiFi.signal_pow.desc())\
    .join(WiFi.map).subquery()
wifi_with_room = db.session.query().add_entity(WiFi, alias=sorted_wifi)\
    .group_by('device_id')
```

So here `wifi_with_room` is list of rows with model `Wifi` and `WiFi.map` as list of models `WiFiMap` that match (based on `WiFi.bssid == WiFiMap.bssid`). But I don't know how I'm supposed to join `wifi_with_room` together with `Device`. I tried

```
db.session.query(Device).outerjoin(wifi_with_room)
```

But that gives me error

> Every derived table must have its own alias

So then I tried

```
db.session.query(Device).outerjoin(wifi_with_room.alias('wifi'))
```

But it returned

> AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'alias'

What I want to achieve is list of rows that have:

- model `Device` (and all it's elements)
- in `Device.room` name of the room that's returned from `WiFiMap.name` by matching `WiFi.device_id == Device.id` and then `WiFiMap.bssid == WiFi.bssid`

---

Here are my models:

```
class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'devices'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mac = db.Column(db.Text)
    vendor = db.Column(db.Text)
    model = db.Column(db.Text)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    resolution_h = db.Column(db.Integer)
    resolution_w = db.Column(db.Integer)
    system_version = db.Column(db.Text)
    cpu_model = db.Column(db.Text)
    gpu = db.Column(db.Text)
    gpu_clock = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ram = db.Column(db.Integer)
    layouts = db.Column(db.Text)
    screen_size = db.Column(db.Float)
    screen_density = db.Column(db.Integer)
    imei = db.Column(db.Integer)
    density_cat = db.Column(db.Text)
    graphics_cat = db.Column(db.Text)
    type = db.Column(db.Text)
    last_active = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
    unavailable = db.Column(db.Integer)

class WiFi(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wifi'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('devices.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True)
    bssid = db.Column(db.String(17), index=True)
    ssid = db.Column(db.Text)
    signal_pow = db.Column(db.Integer)

class WiFiMap(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wifi_map'

    room = db.Column(db.Integer)
    x = db.Column(db.Integer)
    y = db.Column(db.Integer)
    bssid = db.Column(db.String(17), db.ForeignKey('wifi.bssid'), primary_key=True)
    ssid = db.Column(db.Text)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    wifi = db.relationship('WiFi', backref='map', lazy='immediate')
```

Comment: Try adding `.subquery()` to the end of `wifi_with_room = ...`. Also, which database do you use?

Comment: Ok, after that, `db.session.query(Device).outerjoin(wifi_with_room)` has all records from `devices` table, but how I can get the room/wifi model assigned to each row? I'm using MySQL

Comment: just add it to results: replace `query(Device)` with `query(Device, wifi_with_room.CCC`) where `CCC` is the column name.